# Trying to decode json with a strange initial structure

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

I have a problem with a json code structure that I can't decode to swift.
The tree in text looks like this:

```
{
"features": [
    {
        "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [
                21.9877132,
                38.9953683
            ],
            "type": "Point"
        },
        "properties": {
            "country": "Greece",
            "countrycode": "GR",
            "extent": [
                19.2477876,
                41.7488889,
                29.7296986,
                34.7006096
            ],
            "name": "Greece",
            "osm_id": 192307,
            "osm_key": "place",
            "osm_type": "R",
            "osm_value": "country",
            "type": "country"
        },
        "type": "Feature"
    },strong text
```

[this is the link to json](https://photon.komoot.io/api/?q=Greece)

I was trying to get the coordinates and country code.
I tried a lot of options but none worked, I leave here my first attempt, that doesn't work but it was the one that first made sense for me to try:

```
import Foundation 

struct features: Codable {
  let features: [Features]
}

struct Features: Codable {

  let geometry: [Geometry] 
  let properties: [Properties]
}

struct Geometry: Codable {
  let coordinates: [Double]
}

struct Properties: Codable {
  let country, countrycode, name: String?
}
```

and the code to decode:

```
var coordinates = [features]()
let urlString = "https://photon.komoot.io/api/?q=Greece"
if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let jsonCord = try? decoder.decode([features].self, from: data) {
            coordinates = jsonCord
            
        }
    }
}
```

Any help that can show me a way to solve this problem would be much appreciated

Comment: The first step towards solving this is by using proper error handling, use `try` with a `do/catch` instead of `try?` and print the error in the catch clause

Comment: The root object (as well as `geometry` and `properties`) is clearly a dictionary, not an array. (note the `{}`) And please name structs always with starting uppercase letter. And **never** load data from a remote URL with synchronous `Data(contentsOf:`

Comment: structs always with starting uppercased, check.  Remote URLwill not be in use, just here for the question. And yes they are a dictionary, and I don't know how to go around that. Thank you vadian for your time

Comment: A dictionary becomes a struct (without brackets). As Joakim wrote print the `error`, it tells you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: @MárcioSilva `[features].self` is wrong what you actually need is `features.self` but note that all structures should start with an uppercase letter I would name it `Features` and a single feature (array element) `Feature`. `struct Features: Codable {` `let features: [Feature]` `}` and change you second structure to `struct Feature: Codable {` `let geometry: [Geometry]` `let properties: [Properties]` `}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data model should look like that:

```
struct Features: Codable {
    let features: [Feature]
}

struct Feature: Codable {
    let geometry: Geometry
    let properties: Properties
}

struct Geometry: Codable {
    let coordinates: [Double]
}

struct Properties: Codable {
    let country, countrycode, name: String?
}
```

and the code to decode:

```
var coordinates: [Feature] = []
let urlString = "https://photon.komoot.io/api/?q=Greece"
if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let jsonCord = try? decoder.decode(Features.self, from: data) {
            coordinates = jsonCord.features
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a special JSON format called GeoJSON.

In iOS 13 / macOS 15 Apple introduced an API in `MapKit` to decode this format: [MKGeoJSONDecoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkgeojsondecoder)

To get the coordinate and the country code you need only one custom struct.

```
import MapKit

struct Country : Decodable {
    let countrycode : String
}

let url = URL(string: "https://photon.komoot.io/api/?q=Greece")!
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
    if let error = error { print(error); return }
    
    do {
        let result = try MKGeoJSONDecoder().decode(data!) as! [MKGeoJSONFeature]
        if let feature = result.first,
           let propertyData = feature.properties {
            let country = try JSONDecoder().decode(Country.self, from: propertyData)
            print(country.countrycode)
            if let annotations = feature.geometry as? [MKPointAnnotation],
               let coordinate = annotations.first?.coordinate {
                print(coordinate)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra info vadian, this is very useful to know.